# Room database - Retrieve @Relation

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-livedata

Im trying to retrieve full models from Room database, but without success.

My database setup is the following:

```
@Entity(tableName = "Message",
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = User::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("userId"))])
data class Message(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Long = 9L,
        var userId: Long = 0L,
        var content: String = "",
)

@Entity(tableName = "Attachment",
        foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Message::class, parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("messageId"))])
data class Attachment(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: String = "",
        var messageId: Long = 0L,
        var url: String = ""
)

@Entity(tableName = "User")
data class User(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Long = 0L,
        var name: String = "",
        var avatarId: String = ""
)
```

DB Relationship:
- One message belongs to one user & One message has multiple attachments

I want now to be able to retrieve directly from database the `LiveData<List<FullMessage>>`, where:

```
class FullMessage(
        val id: Int,
        val content: String,
        val user: User,
        val attachments: List<Attachment>
)
```

On Dao side, I know I am able to do:

```
@Query("SELECT * from Message")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<FullMessage>>
```

Im missing now the use of @Relation annotation from Room in FullMessage class. How can I retrieve the model FullMessage?

Comment: Inside your FullMessage class you need two relations on both user and  attachment. Something like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/9b48a3903118bbff7b6d2e4ac094a54a

Comment: Did you find the solution to this issue? With @realtion on values it works but with LiveData I am getting null.